# App game is finished, but when publishing to the ipad, game App will not install

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, ipad, air

Thank you, for Reading my question post.  **i will make it simple & easy to read post**
-> These are the steps i took, please help troubleshoot.

1) Finished the **Game App** on a **Windows PC** with **Adobe Flash pro cc**

2) >"Steps Before exporting on Publishing setting"<

- A)"Created" Apple **Certificate** {"Tools"-Windows OpenSSL, to create
  Apple Cert. on windows pc." (**Completed**)
     //Note its a Develop Cert.//
- B) "Created" **App iD** (**Completed**)
- C) "Created" **Provisonals Profile** with the (ipad device, cert, app
  id). (**Completed**)

3) Publishing Settings   -"**Target**" ****4.0*** ****Adobe air*** * for ****IOS****

4) install app on itunes transfer and sync with ipad **!Done**

5) on the ipad tap the app to install and it should work

### Whats happening Now!

- App will never install "Stuck in a Frozen State" & " Icon Seems to be Grey"

### My Tech Specs ##

- Windows 7

  - Flash Pro CC
  - 4.0 Air for ios

    - AS(3)
  - Ipad Air Ios 7

*"I do not own a Mac pc"*

### Random troubleshooting thoughts

is it ipad air ios 7 hurting me? or do i have to add some actionscript 3 code in my actions in flash.

or is it my windows pc export to my ipad. at this point my brain is fryed i need some serious help

so upset i finished a game i can't even try it on the ipad for development testing it is my first game i ever created in my life. runs fine on "mobile testing device" when you test movie "in flash pro cc on windows".

thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

This is a certificate issue. The infinite install/gray icon issue is specific to iOS 7; previously it would give you an alert saying it failed to install. Note that this is *not* an iOS 7 issue, just the way iOS 7 displays the same issue present in all versions of iOS.

You **must** use a mobile provisioning profile that includes the device's UDID, unless you are downloading from the App Store or using an Enterprise license. Additionally, you can no longer use an app to get the UDID and you *must* use iTunes instead. If your UDID starts with "FFFFFF" or similar, it's wrong.

Additionally, the P12 file you generate **must** be generated using Adobe's process (you can find a link to instructions in the window where you set the certs). Other methods may fail. Even further, I have never successfully converted a .cer file to P12 using a Windows util. I always have to use Keychain on OS X, although I never tried any command line tools.

You also need to make sure you are using the correct profile. If your device is set up as a Developer device (I believe you have to do this in Xcode, though there may be other ways), you can install a Development Profile app on your device. If you do not, you can only use Ad Hoc to install. App Store Profile apps cannot be installed on common devices; only by Apple or through the App Store.

And one final thing: make sure your cert matches your profile. You have two types of certificates: Developer and Distribution. If you are using a developer profile, you must use a Developer cert. If you are using an Ad Hoc or App Store profile, you must use a Distribution cert.

Answer (score 0):

I was also banging my head against the wall with this one... and about a week or so later, after retracing my steps, and making sure I've jumped through all the Apple provisioning hoops and keychain bs.  No need for xCode in any step of the process either, I'm all Flash Pro CC.

Anyway here it is, after adding the client's device to the device list in Apple's Dev Center, I failed to remember (and thanks to an old Lee Brimlow video) that you have to **click the checkbox next to the devices listed in the development provisioning profile** you will be using.  Click Edit on your provisioning profile, click the missing checkboxes, save the changes, download, replace your dev prov, publish again, do the iTunes sync and boom.  No more gray installing problem.

Hope this helps someone.